# Changing HTML with Java(Spring)

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I am a newbie at Spring and I am writing a rental system for movies. I have a Controller where I can get a list of all movies which are still rented (marked by digit "1" as a status in my Database) and which are already have been returned(marked as "0").

Now currently, when I call the page I see all the rented movies with the current status "1" or "0" as well as already returned movies which can still be returned and have a checkbox (which shouldn't be possible.

My question is, how can I change the HTML in the following way:

1. The status "1" or "0" changes to "rented" and "returned"
2. I want to remove the checkbox on all movies which already have been returned.

My code:

```
@Controller
public class MovieController {

@Autowired
private MovieService movieService;

@GetMapping("/home")
public String home(Model model) {
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/movieList")
public String listAllMovies(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("listMovies", movieService.findNotRented());
    return "movies";
}

@GetMapping("/search")
public String findByOption(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "search") String search, 
@RequestParam("options") String options) {
    if (options.equals("movie")) {
        model.addAttribute("listMovies", movieService.findByName(search));
    } else if (options.equals("actor")) {
        model.addAttribute("listMovies", movieService.findMovieByActor(search));
    } else if (options.equals("genre")) {
        model.addAttribute("listMovies", movieService.findMovieByGenre(search));
    }
    return "movies";
}

@GetMapping("/rentedList")
public String findRentedMovies(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("listMovies", movieService.findRentedMovies());
    return "rented";
}

@GetMapping("/rentMovie")
public String rentMovie(Model model, @RequestParam int id) {
    model.addAttribute("listMovies", movieService.rentMovie(id));
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/deleteRentedMovie")
public String deleterentedMovie(Model model, @RequestParam int id) {
    model.addAttribute("listMovies", movieService.deleteRentedMovie(id));
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/rentMovie2")
public String rentMovie2(Model model, @RequestParam("idChecked") List<Integer> id) {
    if (id != null) {
        for (Integer idInt : id) {

            model.addAttribute("listMovies", movieService.rentMovie(idInt));
        }
    }
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/deleteRentedMovie2")
public String deleterentedMovie(Model model, @RequestParam("idChecked") List<Integer> id) {
    if (id != null) {
        for (Integer idInt : id) {
            model.addAttribute("listMovies", movieService.deleteRentedMovie(idInt));
        }
    }
    return "index";
}

}
```

Thymeleaf

```
 <h1>Movie List</h1>
    <form action="/deleteRentedMovie2">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Time rented</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Select</th>
            </tr>

            <tr th:each="movie : ${listMovies}">
                <td th:text="${movie.title}"></td>
                <td th:text="${movie.date}"></td>
                <td th:text="${movie.status}"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" th:name="idChecked" th:value="${movie.id}"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Return Movie">
    </form>
```

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the status I would something like:

```
<td>
    <span th:if="${movie.status == 1}">rented</span>
    <span th:if="${movie.status == 0}">returned</span>
</td>
```

You could also use the Elvis operator but it is maybe less readable.

For the checkbox:

```
<td><input th:unless="${movie.status == 0}" type="checkbox" th:name="idChecked" th:value="${movie.id}"></td>
```